# TLS server: In state connection received CLIENT ALERT: Fatal - Unknown CA

Tags: rabbitmq, tls1.2, amqp, rabbitmq-exchange, mtls

I did enable TLS on my local, below are the setting in the rabbitMQ.config file.

```
log.console = true
log.console.level = debug
log.file.level = debug

listeners.tcp = none
listeners.ssl.default = 5671

ssl_options.cacertfile = C:/Users/UserId/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/result-new/ca_certificate.pem
ssl_options.certfile   = C:/Users/UserId/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/result-new/server_PNQ1-LP98R10J3_certificate.pem
ssl_options.keyfile    = C:/Users/UserId/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/result-new/server_PNQ1-LP98R10J3_key.pem
ssl_options.verify     = verify_none
ssl_options.fail_if_no_peer_cert = false
```

The RabbitMQ service is getting started, but when I try to connect to the rabbitMQ using code it is throwing error :

```
RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable
 ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.)
 ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.PartialFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ThrowIfExceptional()
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.<AuthenticateAsClientAsync>b__64_2(IAsyncResult iar)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SslHelper.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<TcpUpgrade>b__0(SslOption opts)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SslHelper.TcpUpgrade(Stream tcpStream, SslOption options)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler..ctor(AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, Func`2 socketFactory, TimeSpan connectionTimeout, TimeSpan readTimeout, TimeSpan writeTimeout)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.IProtocolExtensions.CreateFrameHandler(IProtocol protocol, AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, ArrayPool`1 pool, Func`2 socketFactory, TimeSpan connectionTimeout, TimeSpan readTimeout, TimeSpan writeTimeout)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateFrameHandler(AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.EndpointResolverExtensions.SelectOne[T](IEndpointResolver resolver, Func`2 selector)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at RabbitMQ.Client.EndpointResolverExtensions.SelectOne[T](IEndpointResolver resolver, Func`2 selector)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.AutorecoveringConnection.Init(IEndpointResolver endpoints)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IEndpointResolver endpointResolver, String clientProvidedName)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IEndpointResolver endpointResolver, String clientProvidedName)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(String clientProvidedName)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection()
   at RabbitMQ.Explore.Program.RabbitMQWithSSLEnable() in C:\Users\E5695455\Desktop\RabbitMQ-RnD\RabbitMQ.Explore-master\RabbitMQ.Explore-master\RabbitMQ.Explore\Program.cs:line 167
```

And on rabbitMQ logs side, below is the error

```
2023-09-13 17:29:45.329000+05:30 [notice] <0.3749.0> TLS server: In state connection received CLIENT ALERT: Fatal - Unknown CA
2023-09-13 17:29:45.329000+05:30 [notice] <0.3749.0> 
2023-09-13 17:29:45.329000+05:30 [info] <0.3752.0> accepting AMQP connection <0.3752.0> ([::1]:61235 -> [::1]:5671)
2023-09-13 17:29:45.330000+05:30 [error] <0.3752.0> closing AMQP connection <0.3752.0> ([::1]:61235 -> [::1]:5671):
2023-09-13 17:29:45.330000+05:30 [error] <0.3752.0> {inet_error,{tls_alert,{unknown_ca,"TLS server: In state connection received CLIENT ALERT: Fatal - Unknown CA\n"}}}
2023-09-13 17:29:45.330000+05:30 [debug] <0.3755.0> Closing all channels from connection '[::1]:61235 -> [::1]:5671' because it has been closed
```

I did checked with the https://www.rabbitmq.com/troubleshooting-ssl.html, everything looks fine.
I created certificate using tls-gen https://github.com/rabbitmq/tls-gen

Using below code for rabbitMQ Connection:

```
try
            {
                string rabbitmqHostName = "PNQ1-LP98R10J3";
                string rabbitmqServerName = "PNQ1-LP98R10J3";
                string certificateFilePath = "C:\\\\Users\\\\UserId\\\\AppData\\\\Roaming\\\\RabbitMQ\\\\fromclient\\\\client_vwmazadsolapac4_certificate.pem";
                string certificatePassphrase = "";
                string rabbitmqUsername = "test";
                string rabbitmqPassword = "test";
                var mTLSEnabled = false;
                var factory = new ConnectionFactory();

                factory.Uri = new Uri($"amqps://{rabbitmqUsername}:{rabbitmqPassword}@{rabbitmqHostName}:5671");


                // Note: This should NEVER be "localhost"
                factory.Ssl.ServerName = rabbitmqServerName;

                if (mTLSEnabled)
                {
                    // Path to my .p12 file.
                    factory.Ssl.CertPath = certificateFilePath;
                    // Passphrase for the certificate file - set through OpenSSL
                    factory.Ssl.CertPassphrase = certificatePassphrase;
                }

                factory.Ssl.Enabled = true;

                // Make sure TLS 1.2 is supported & enabled by your operating system
                factory.Ssl.Version = SslProtocols.Tls12;

                // This is the default RabbitMQ secure port
                factory.Port = AmqpTcpEndpoint.UseDefaultPort;
                factory.VirtualHost = "/";

                using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
                {
                    using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
                    {
                        Logger.LogWriter($"{System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name} - Successfully connected and opened a channel");
                        Console.WriteLine("Successfully connected and opened a channel");
                        channel.QueueDeclare("rabbitmq-dotnet-test", false, false, false, null);
                        Logger.LogWriter($"{System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name} - Successfully declared a queue");
                        Console.WriteLine("Successfully declared a queue");
                        channel.QueueDelete("rabbitmq-dotnet-test");
                        Console.WriteLine("Successfully deleted the queue");
                        Logger.LogWriter($"{System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name} - Successfully deleted a queue");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                var error = ex.ToString();
                Logger.LogWriter($"{System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name} - {error}");
                System.Console.WriteLine(error);
            }
```

I am not able to get the reason it is throwing error. I tried the things given in https://www.rabbitmq.com/troubleshooting-ssl.htmt and that seems to be working fine.

rabbitmq-diagnostics.bat --silent tls_versions
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCioe.png)

rabbitmq-diagnostics.bat cipher_suites --format openssl --silent
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noh7d.png)

Use OpenSSL Tools to Test TLS Connections
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjNS0.png)

Comment: The error actually tells you what's wrong. You tried to use a certificate issued by an unknown Certificate Authority. Most likely, a self-signed certificate.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: The issue is resolved, as you said the installed certificate was missing with Certificate Authority. I uninstall the existing certificate and reinstall it in "Trusted Root Service Authorities". Thanks.